# Laravel Redirect::intended() conditional fallbacks

Tags: php, laravel, http-redirect, laravel-routing

To my understanding, `Redirect::intended()` will redirect to a users intended page prior to logging in, or fall back to a url that can be passed as an argument.

My question is this: How would I make it so that it first checks if there is an intended url in the session, if not it does a `Redirect::back()` instead, and if that fails it will redirect to the users profile which would be the same as `Redirect::route('users.show', Auth::user()->username);`

Comment: What is your criteria to define a `Redirect::back()` failure so as to trigger the next `Redirect::route(...)` knowing that `Redirect::back()` redirects always to the *referer*

Comment: If someone were linked directly to the login page, there wouldn't be a referer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Notes:

1. Partially, the behavior you expected can be attained by passing the referer to `Redirect::intended` as parameter the `referer`.
2. The rest depends on the criteria of a `Redirect::back` failure as you meant it.

## Answer:

Here is my take

```
// Retrieve the referer - Ripped from Redirect::back()
$back = Redirect::getUrlGenerator()->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');

// your expected Fall back Redirection logic
if (itSucceed($back)) {
    Redirect::intended($back);
} else {
    Redirect::route(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Made a few changes though based on Marwelln's answer. Used `Request::header('referer')` instead of the long chain in your answer.

Comment: You are right `Request::header('referer')`is concise, laravelish and yields the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fallbackUrl = Request::header('referer') ?: URL::route('users.show', Auth::user()->username);

Redirect::intended($fallbackUrl);
```

Comment: You should explain what your code here is doing. Answers containing nothing but uncommented code are low quality.

Comment: Thanks! Fortunately, I could understand it fine; however, James is right in the fact that you should have explained your solution. I love how simple your solution is though. :D