# Laravel - Clear Redirect::intended()

Tags: php, redirect, laravel

As a follow-up question to: [Laravel Redirect::intended() conditional fallbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967131/laravel-redirectintended-conditional-fallbacks)

I am having a problem where after the intended URL session is set, it remains in the session even if the user decides not to login and instead browses to another part of the site. Later, if the user decides to login with being forced to by a filter, the old intended url is used.

So, I suppose my question is this; how would I go about clearing the intended url if the user is not attempting to login?

Comment: Can you post the filter code? Redirect::guest should set the intended Url

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The intended URL is stored in Session with the key `url.intended`. If you need to forget the value, you can do `Session::forget('url.intended');`. Therefore, the old intended URL will not be used.

You need to determine when you need to forget the value and when you need to remember it.

My source: the [Laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/81816f596c255b11b9a8e32188e8bfca9b2b9495/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L87-L101)! This information is not in the documentation.

Comment: Please change it to Session::forget('url.intended'); to avoid confusion

Comment: `url.intended` not intented `Session::forget('url.intended');`

Comment: VladislavDimitrov & namal: fixed, thanks.